# Issue in window.Echo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am following **[this tutorial to implement Pusher in Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting)**

Below were the step by step things done.

1. `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`
2. `npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js`
3. instantiated the Echo instance in your `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`
4. Initialized the pusher key in `env` and in `bootstrap.js` file.

Finally, I wrote below code in blade.

```
<script>
    debugger;
    window.Echo.channel('SendMessageChannel.1')
        .listen('.App.Events.SendMessageEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
</script>
```

also added `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` reference in layout.
While debugging, I found that window.Echo is undefined.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you install laravel-echo and pusher-js, you need to run `npm run dev` so that app.js can have those both libraries.

Comment: Bounty 500 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102342/listen-callback-is-not-working-in-pusher-api-laravel-5-4